# Visual Studio C/C++ extension shows error message even if the code is correct

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, mingw, function-definition

My Visual Studio compiler is showing me error messages even when the code is correct.

Even on a simple code like,

```
 #include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int add(firstNumber, secondNumber){
        int result=firstNumber+secondNumber;
        return result;
    }
    int out=add(10,30);
    printf("%d", out);
    return 0;
}
```

It's showing the massage,

> expected a ';', line 4

and

> identifier "out" is undefined, line 9

The code runs well. But it's frustrating seeing those red lines and the error messages on my code.

Note: I'm using MinGW as a C path

Comment: There's no way you have this code compiling.

Comment: Nested functions (like your `add`) are not supported in *Standard* C or C++. Some compilers may support them as extensions. Try moving your `add` function to before, and outside, `main`.

Comment: **C and C++ are *different* programming languages.** I recommend to learn C, it is simpler. Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/), [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c), and the documentation of your C compiler. I heard that mingw is a variant of  the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler: invoke it with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: I'll point out that, compiler extensions for nested functions aside, the parameter types are not identified. Is that also a compiler extension?

Comment: And **your code above is *very* incorrect**

Comment: @sweenish: yes. Ancient versions of C compilers assumed all variables without types were `int`, and some C and C++ compilers keep that as an extension.  This was never part of any C standard though.

Comment: @MooingDuck That's atrocious. But good to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither C nor C++ Standard allows nested function definitions as in this program

```
 #include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int add(firstNumber, secondNumber){
        int result=firstNumber+secondNumber;
        return result;
    }
    int out=add(10,30);
    printf("%d", out);
    return 0;
}
```

where the function `add` is defined within the function `main`.

Moreover the identifiers `firstNumber` and `secondNumber` in the parameter list do not have type specifiers.

You have to move the function definition outside main. For example

```
#include<stdio.h>

int add( int firstNumber, int secondNumber )
{
    int result = firstNumber + secondNumber;
    return result;
}

int main( void ){
    int out=add(10,30);
    printf("%d", out);
    return 0;
}
```

In C++ you could use a lambda expression instead of the function `add`. For example

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    auto add = []( int firstNumber, int secondNumber )
    {
        return firstNumber + secondNumber;
    };

    int out = add(10,30);

    printf( "%d\n", out );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the function you defined in main, C doesn't support functions defined inside other functions. Your code should look like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
    

int add(firstNumber, secondNumber){
    int result=firstNumber+secondNumber;
    return result;
}

int main(){
    int out=add(10,30);
    printf("%d", out);
    return 0;
}
```